# Maven War Plugin : Specify Regular Expression to exclude libraries within web-inf/lib

Tags: java, regex, maven, tomcat

As we have around 8 projects which are having same dependencies and getting deployed to tomcat. Because of memory it used to consume to load all these classes we decided to move all the common jars to custom tomcat base installation and make individual wars having only the required custom libraries.

For this to be done, we need to alter the maven war plugin configuration where we can specify the regular expression for excluding libraries like below :

%regex[WEB-INF/lib/TODO]

I would like some help in figuring out the exact regular expression which i can put in here to  avoid all the common libraries and include the required custom libraries. below are some of the custom library names which needs to be part of WEB-INF/lib within war:

1. xmax-common.jar
2. xmax-services.jar
3. xmax-model.jar
4. momentum-core.jar

Your suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using regexp to include these libs, try something like:

```
<configuration>
    <packagingExcludes>%regex[WEB-INF/lib/(?!xmax)(?!momentum).*.jar</packagingExcludes>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to include only needed packages instead of exclude unnecessary  libs

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>

    <configuration>
        <packagingIncludes>
            WEB-INF/lib/xmax-common.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/xmax-services.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/xmax-model.jar,
            WEB-INF/lib/momentum-core.jar
        </packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That will do. Thank you. Rather than keep on adding entries as we proceed ahead, i was thinking of doing it using regular expressions, which is kind of generic way of solving the issue.